# Symfony 3 - An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I just try symfony 3 and I am on insert data into database using Doctrine ORM.
When I try to run my query

```
$customer = new Customer();
$customer->setAddress('Some Address');
$customer->setName('Customer 1');

$order->setQuantity('100');
$order->setDate(date('Y-m-d'));
$order->setCustomer($customer);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($customer);
$em->persist($order);
$em->flush();
```

but it returns an exception :

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: "An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver" at /home/hei/Sites/practice/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 121
```

Parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: practice
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
```

Config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
```

I also check if the extension is enabled and loaded via php -m and phpinfo(). It says that PDO & PDO_Mysql is enabled.

Then add these two lines in php.ini:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

but I still got the same PDO Exception.

My OS is Ubuntu 17.1

Comment: Do you have same php version for cli and web? Create script `<?php phpinfo();` and check if mysql extensions is available there

Answer (score 33):

I believe php-mysql package missing in your system. Install the package using the command

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

I hope this will fix your issue.

I think you need to restart Apache also in order to fix the issue. After installing php-mysql use the following command to restart Apache

```
 sudo service apache2 restart.
```

Answer (score 3):

For me I added these 2 lines in `/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini` as they were already present in

**/usr/lib/php/5.6/php.ini-development**

```
extension=pdo.so

extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Then did:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I could then flush entity to database.

Hope this works for anyone else in future.

Answer (score 1):

On my system (Fedora), a package called php-mysqlnd was required. I installed it by running:

```
dnf install php-mysqlnd
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to change MySQL port number from `null` to `3306`. That's it.
I think you don't have MySQL password that's why you didn't write anything.

Have a good day.

Comment: The "null" on the port parameter it means that you're using the default port "3306", so I don't think that this will solve the problem, I think there is a problem related to the mysql driver extension on php.ini

Answer (score 0):

In my case (in windows) i have installed [mysql driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/).

Answer (score 0):

In WAMPServer and **possibly other configurations**, there may be a separate `php.ini` for your command line PHP. Ensure that you enabling your modules in the right .ini (ideally both ini's)